# What is the difference between a BIOS chip and a PCH

Tags: integrated-circuit, motherboard, x86

From what I can gather, the BIOS chip is a loadable memory space that handles initial I/O, system checks and CAN configure certain things like power states and clock rates, before handing operation over to the chipset/CPU. The chipset then orchestrates connection and throughput between CPU and peripheral devices i.e. RAM, PCI lanes etc.

Is that the main difference? If so, why don't we just let the chipset handle all the initial boot stages?

Please close if off-topic and I will ask in superuser.

Comment: The BIOS is just code storage. It doesn't actually do anything itself. It holds the instructions which the CPU executes in order to setup/configure all that stuff.

Comment: BIOS chip is memory chip where BIOS is located. PCH is the controller HUB for Intel platforms which takes care of all the peripherals interfacing offloading main processor .

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS is a program stored in a read-only memory (the "BIOS chip) that does initialization and configuration of the computer system, and loads the operating system.  This program runs in the main CPU on power-up or reset.  When the BIOS program is finishes its job, it turns control of the system over to the operating system.

Comment: So when OS firmware projects like Core-Boot talk about a "payload" (like OpenFirmware, OpenBIOS, or TianoCore), are they referring to this program?

Comment: To be fair, the BIOS in personal computers from the last 20 years is stored in some sort of EEPROM, such as flash, so it's not really ROM - that's why you can update your motherboard BIOS (and potentially brick it).

Comment: This answer is actually a bit mistaken.  What you are describing is a bootloader.   The actual idea of a BIOS is that it provides the basic I/O routines to support an operating system.  But the bootloader code was stored with it.  And then multitasking operating systems needed to deactivate BIOS and handle I/O themselves.  Later on BIOS started sometimes having some ongoing role again for some hardware specifics, power management, etc.

Comment: What is UEFI? It is stored on MB.